# Following PATTERN 3 Deployment ,Not able to consume apis in Gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

[2024-04-02 06:03:34,299] ERROR - SynapseConfiguration No endpoint exists by the key/name : aj--v1.7_APIsandboxEndpoint
[2024-04-02 06:03:34,301]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : e7fc3392-8629-47db-8067-964112f604e1 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-04-02 06:03:34,306]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : aj--v1.7_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2024-04-02 06:03:34,306] ERROR - EndpointAdminServiceProxy Error deleting endpoint from gateway
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: No endpoint exists by the key/name : aj--v1.7_APIsandboxEndpoint
at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1800) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271_14.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271.14]
at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.removeEndpoint(SynapseConfiguration.java:1218) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271_14.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271.14]
at org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.service.EndpointAdmin.deleteEndpoint(EndpointAdmin.java:292) ~[org.wso2.carbon.endpoint_4.7.131.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.EndpointAdminServiceProxy.deleteEndpoint_aroundBody2(EndpointAdminServiceProxy.java:82) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.EndpointAdminServiceProxy.deleteEndpoint(EndpointAdminServiceProxy.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI_aroundBody98(APIGatewayAdmin.java:831) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI(APIGatewayAdmin.java:779) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI_aroundBody100(APIGatewayAdmin.java:898) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI(APIGatewayAdmin.java:886) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.unDeployAPI_aroundBody8(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:302) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.unDeployAPI(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:259) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAPI_aroundBody0(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:96) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAPI(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:86) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayJMSMessageListener.lambda$0_aroundBody12(GatewayJMSMessageListener.java:170) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayJMSMessageListener.lambda$0(GatewayJMSMessageListener.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_362]
[2024-04-02 06:03:34,306] ERROR - InMemoryAPIDeployer Error deploying e7fc3392-8629-47db-8067-964112f604e1 in Gateway
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while deleting the endpoint fileNo endpoint exists by the key/name : aj--v1.7_APIsandboxEndpoint
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.EndpointAdminServiceProxy.deleteEndpoint_aroundBody2(EndpointAdminServiceProxy.java:88) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.EndpointAdminServiceProxy.deleteEndpoint(EndpointAdminServiceProxy.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI_aroundBody98(APIGatewayAdmin.java:831) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI(APIGatewayAdmin.java:779) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI_aroundBody100(APIGatewayAdmin.java:898) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.unDeployAPI(APIGatewayAdmin.java:886) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.unDeployAPI_aroundBody8(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:302) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.unDeployAPI(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:259) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAPI_aroundBody0(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:96) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.InMemoryAPIDeployer.deployAPI(InMemoryAPIDeployer.java:86) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayJMSMessageListener.lambda$0_aroundBody12(GatewayJMSMessageListener.java:170) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.listeners.GatewayJMSMessageListener.lambda$0(GatewayJMSMessageListener.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_362]
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: No endpoint exists by the key/name : aj--v1.7_APIsandboxEndpoint
at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1800) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271_14.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271.14]
at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.removeEndpoint(SynapseConfiguration.java:1218) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271_14.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271.14]
at org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.service.EndpointAdmin.deleteEndpoint(EndpointAdmin.java:292) ~[org.wso2.carbon.endpoint_4.7.131.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.EndpointAdminServiceProxy.deleteEndpoint_aroundBody2(EndpointAdminServiceProxy.java:82) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.101.jar:?]
... 12 more
[2024-04-02 06:03:34,306] ERROR - GatewayJMSMessageListener Error in deploying artifacts for e7fc3392-8629-47db-8067-964112f604e1in the Gateway

Comment: Above logs which been generated by APIM gateway.

Comment: Are you deploying this on kubernetes? If so, can you go into the gateway pod and check whether the API has been deployed successfully? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/gateway-apis/gateway-v2/gateway-v2/#operation/getAPIArtifacts